# Console.WriteLine() doesn't exist error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I have little problem because I'm trying to run a powershell script in a console but Visual Studio is telling that `Console.WriteLine()` or `Console.ReadKey()` doesn't exist

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, rather copy and paste it into your question. What have you tried to fix this?

Comment: Post the *code* and the *actual compiler error*. Did you forget to import the `System` namespace? Are you trying to use `Console` in a web application?

Comment: This may happens when name of the namespace contains "Console" at the end:. This code will give the same error: `using System;

namespace FileTranser.Run.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your class:

```
using System;
```

The using statement is usually included as default, but if you use tools to "Remove Unnecessary Usings", then it may get removed. If you then later add code that requires the `System` namespace, then you have to include it again.

You could probably also fix the issue in by placing the marker on the `Console` in the Visual Studio code editor, and press Ctrl + '.'(period), to open the Quick Actions and Refactoring context menu.

Comment: the problem came from visual studio

Comment: @charlo Yes, but have you checked that you have included the `using System;` statement in the top of the class that has this problem?